# Finding r-Combinations of a Vector of Strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations

I'm trying to generate all possible r-combination of a given list of strings. For example :

```
vector<string> original(n);
original[0] = "Brown";
original[1] = "Yellow";
original[2] = "Blue";
```

In this case, n = 3 (3 colors), and for example, if the user inputs r = 2, the program must print :

```
    >Brown, Yellow
    >Brown, Blue
    >Yellow, Blue
```

Everyone I have talked to says to use the next_permutation route but that gives me repetition (I am looking for combinations, not permutations..... so in the example above, after the set (Yellow, Blue), (Blue, Yellow) should not be included).

Comment: Can the input contain repetitions?

Comment: If you know the algorithm to output combinations based on a series of bits, you can still use next_permutation() on the bit pattern.  Each bit that's "on" indicates an item in the combination.

Comment: The output cannot contain repetitions.

Comment: Can the **input** contain repetitions. Would `{"Brown", "Yellow", "Brown"} be valid input?

Comment: Yes that would be a valid input.

Comment: Removing the content of your own question after you have asked and received an answer it goes against the spirit of StackOverflow. As such, I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

1) Create a series of 3 bits.

2) Since `r` is 2, initialize the two rightmost bits to 1.

3) Output the items in the vector that correspond with the bits that are on, for example, if `bitarray[0]` is 1, then output `original[0]`, if `bitarray[1]` is 1, then output `original[1]`, etc.

4) Call `next_permutation()` on the bits to get the "next" bit pattern.

Repeat steps 3 and 4 until next_permutation() is `false`.

So basically, you need a bit array of `n` items to start off with and initialize the rightmost `r` bits to 1.  Then you use `next_permutation` to change the bit pattern.  I recommend you do this on paper first, to see how it all works.

Below is an example.  It is hard-coded for 3 items, so take it for what it's worth.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void OutputVector (const std::vector<std::string>& theVect, bool* bArray, int nItems)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nItems; ++i)
       if (bArray[i] == true)
         std::cout << theVect[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> original = { "Brown", "Yellow", "Blue" };
    bool myBits[3] = { false };  // everything is false now
    myBits[1] = myBits[2] = true;  // set rightmost bits to true
    do  // start combination generator
    {
       OutputVector(original, myBits, 3);
    } while (next_permutation(myBits, myBits + 3));  // change the bit pattern
}
```

Taking your example:

We start out with this bit pattern (call the array of bits `bitArray`):
`011`

This means we output `original[1]` and `original[2]` because `bitArray[1]` and `bitArray[2]` are "true" (set to 1).

When `next_permutation` is called on these bits, the bit pattern changes to this:
`101`

We output `original[0]` and `original[2]` because `bitArray[0]` and `bitArray[2]` are "true".

`next_permutation` is called, bit array changes:
`110`

`original[0]` and `original[1]` are output.

`next_permutation` will return a false if called again, since there are no more permutations.

Done.

Comment: Go through the algorithm I described above, first with pencil and paper to understand it, and then with real code.  To make this simple, just create a bool array of 3 items and set all the entries to false except for the 2 rightmost entries, which would be entries 1 and 2 (set these to true).  Basically you're using the bool array as a guide in outputing the original array values.

Comment: @Not_NSA_I_Swear - The other answer shows a live example of the algorithm I explained above.  But if you don't understand the C++ aspect of this, that's not important right now -- it's more important to understand how it works algorithmically, which is why you should see this in action by doing this "by hand" with pencil and paper.  Once you get the logic of what's happening, then use any C++ that you've learned (it doesn't have to be a `bitset` like in the example below) to simulate the algorithm.

Comment: @Not_NSA_I_Swear You can sort the original vector by calling `std::sort`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
void Combination(const std::vector<T>& v, std::size_t count)
{
    assert(count <= v.size());
    std::vector<bool> bitset(v.size() - count, 0);
    bitset.resize(v.size(), 1);

    do {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
            if (bitset[i]) {
                std::cout << v[i] << " ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (std::next_permutation(bitset.begin(), bitset.end()));
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/sHuTg7)

Comment: Exactly the way I described.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, which is faster than using `std::next_permutation`:

```
#include "../combinations/combinations"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> original(6);
    original[0] = "Brown";
    original[1] = "Yellow";
    original[2] = "Blue";
    original[3] = "Red";
    original[4] = "Green";
    original[5] = "Purple";
    for_each_combination(original.begin(), original.begin()+3, original.end(),
                         [](auto begin, auto end)
                         {
                              std::cout << "{";
                              bool print_comma = false;
                              for (; begin != end; ++begin)
                              {
                                   if (print_comma)
                                       std::cout << ", ";
                                   print_comma = true;
                                   std::cout << *begin;
                              }
                              std::cout << "}\n";
                              return false;
                         });
}
```

Find [`for_each_combination` here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html).

Output:

```
{Brown, Yellow, Blue}
{Brown, Yellow, Red}
{Brown, Yellow, Green}
{Brown, Yellow, Purple}
{Brown, Blue, Red}
{Brown, Blue, Green}
{Brown, Blue, Purple}
{Brown, Red, Green}
{Brown, Red, Purple}
{Brown, Green, Purple}
{Yellow, Blue, Red}
{Yellow, Blue, Green}
{Yellow, Blue, Purple}
{Yellow, Red, Green}
{Yellow, Red, Purple}
{Yellow, Green, Purple}
{Blue, Red, Green}
{Blue, Red, Purple}
{Blue, Green, Purple}
{Red, Green, Purple}
```

If constrained to C++98, or if you simply prefer named functions, you can do:

```
#include "../combinations/combinations"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool
print(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator begin,
      std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator end)
{
    std::cout << "{";
    bool print_comma = false;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        if (print_comma)
            std::cout << ", ";
        print_comma = true;
        std::cout << *begin;
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
    return false;
}

int
main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> original(6);
    original[0] = "Brown";
    original[1] = "Yellow";
    original[2] = "Blue";
    original[3] = "Red";
    original[4] = "Green";
    original[5] = "Purple";
    for_each_combination(original.begin(), original.begin()+3, original.end(),
                         print);
}
```

Source code is open source under the boost software license, but is not part of boost. Feel free to use.  The intent is that this source code should be free to use, and free use is encouraged.  If your lawyers aren't happy with this license, let me know and I will try to make them happy, gratis.

The same link includes:

```
template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_permutation(BidirIter first,
                     BidirIter mid,
                     BidirIter last,
                     Function f);

template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_reversible_permutation(BidirIter first,
                                BidirIter mid,
                                BidirIter last,
                                Function f);

template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_circular_permutation(BidirIter first,
                              BidirIter mid,
                              BidirIter last,
                              Function f);

template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_reversible_circular_permutation(BidirIter first,
                                         BidirIter mid,
                                         BidirIter last,
                                         Function f);

template <class BidirIter, class Function>
Function
for_each_combination(BidirIter first,
                     BidirIter mid,
                     BidirIter last,
                     Function f);
```

And the code is *fast*.